# Duplication of multi records on tab

Tags: custom-fields, multi-record

I can't reproduce this on the Joomla demo site running 4.6.0, and I didn't have this problem before.  Now on my 4.6.6 site, if I display custom fields with multi records in a tab, the set of records displays multiple times, along with multiple "Edit multi record" buttons.

If I have one record inserted, it shows once.

If I have two records inserted, they each show twice.  (As in example below.)

If I have six records inserted, they each show six times.

I don't have multiple records if I click "Edit multi record", or in "Tab with table" or "Inline" modes.  Only the data display in "Tab" mode.

Is this a bug introduced sometime between 4.6.0 and 4.6.6?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has been [fixed in 4.6.7](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16949). Please upgrade to the latest version or patch your site with [this PR](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6420).